# Remove sweet alert div (which is hidden) after swal.fire function called in vue 3

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuex, sweetalert

I am using **VueSweetalert2** with **Vue 3** and **Vuex 4**. when i call sweet alert function like this

```
this.$swal.fire({
    text: 'Success',
    icon:'success',
})
```

sweet alert **append** one **div** everytime with `display:none` css at the end and before the body tag closed. i want only one div when sweet alert function called. below is an image of lots of div tag with `display:none` css.
let me know if is there any cleanup function or something else that i missed.

[image]

here is my complete code. **i am using Option API not composition in Vue 3**

```
            this.$store.dispatch('store_transaction',{
                amount: amount,
                date_time: date_time,
                note: note || null
            })
            .then(respones => {
                if(respones.status){
                    this.$swal.fire({
                        text: respones.message || 'Success',
                        icon:'success',
                    })
                }
                else{
                    this.$swal.fire({
                        text: respones.message || 'Error',
                        icon:'error',
                    })
                }
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  methods: {
    countUp() {
      this.$swal.fire({
        text: 'Fail',
        icon:'fail',
      })
      this.$store.dispatch('increment').then(() => {
        this.$swal.fire({
          text: 'Success',
          icon:'success',
        })
      })
    }
  }
```

There's no problem when I try.
Can I get the github code?